# como realizar el event prevent default en onclick js

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, onclick, preventdefault

¿Cómo evitar el incumplimiento en un método onclick? Tengo un método en el que también paso un valor personalizado.

```
<a href="#" onclick="callmymethod(24)">Call</a>

function callmymethod(myVal){
    //doing custom things with myVal
    //here I want to prevent default
}
```

al realizar click se agrega el # en la ruta como hago para evitar eso y que me ejecute la funcion que estoy realizando por onclick

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres lograr es que el enlace no intente hacer su accion tipica de redireccion, la almohadilla deberia bastar o dejar el href vacio. En ese caso recomendaria que usaras mejor un boton para este tipo de tareas.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer lo que tu necesitas es un elemento `<button>` en vez de un `<a>`. Se debe preferir el primero por razones de accesibilidad.

Pero como se que nada es perfecto y uno debe jugar con las cartas que tiene no con las que quiere. Aquí van algunas alternativas:

##### 1) window.event

Está sería la forma más usada, en teoría está [obsoleta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), pero en la práctica dudo mucho que se elimine, ya que no han eliminado otras funcionalidades menos usadas y que llevan muchos más años en estado de obsoletas como [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```js
function callmymethod(myVal) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(myVal);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

##### 2) Return false

Los atributos que funcionan como eventos tienen la peculariadad que cortan la propagación cuando se ha retornado false.

Está es la opción que yo te recomendaría para tu caso

```js
function callmymethod(myVal) {
    console.log(arguments);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

Otra variante de esta tecnica es usar el operador [coma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

```js
function callmymethod(myVal) {
    console.log(myVal);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return callmymethod(24),false">Call</a>
```

##### 3) Usar javascript en el href

```js
function callmymethod(myVal) {
    console.log(myVal);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

<sub>Nota: No funciona en el snnipet de SO</sub>

##### 4) href=javascript:void(0)

Muy parecido al anterior, pero usando `onclick`

```js
function callmymethod(myVal) {
    console.log(myVal);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, solo tienes que pasar el evento a la función y así ya puedes usar el preventDefault() o el stopPropagation().

```
<a href="#" onclick="callmymethod(event, 24)">Call</a>

function callmymethod(event, myVal){
  //al final
  event.preventDefault();
}
```